# Adal WPF Client AuthenticationContext AcquireTokenAsync timeouts in one machine but works on another

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm using the following code to sign in to aad from a wpf app using adal. The code throws an TaskCanceled exception when run in one machine, but it works in another just fine (the same .exe).

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
            try
            {
                result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(webApiResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));
                SignInButton.Content = "Clear Cache";
            }
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
               ...
            }
```

Library Version:

```
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.9" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Exception + InnerException Message:

> unknown_error: Unknown error -  A task was canceled

StackTrace:

```
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendHttpMessageAsync>d__67.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendTokenRequestAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__55.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Comment: The request seems timed out ,please check the network firstly  , you could also try [code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) request in browser for testing .

Comment: @NanYu-MSFT thanks for your comment, tested it in the browser as you suggested and it works fine. Still don't know why it doesn't work from the wpf app from this machine and works when I run the very same .exe in another machine. Must be environment related but I can't think what exactly.

Comment: And please check with fiddler to see if AAD returned a response to adal request. adal request is sent to login.microsoftonline.com and starts with authorize?